# How do sum two step responses of the same system in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, controls

I'm trying to plot the response of a control system which has two unit steps - one a t=0 and one at t=0.3

Here is the code I'm using:

```
% Set up the transfer function
numer = [K*K_m*r];
denom = [(L_m*J_e) (L_m*b_m+R_m*J_e) (K_b*K_m+R_m*b_m) K*K_m*r];
transfun = tf(numer, denom);

% Apply a step function at t=0
[y,T] = step(transfun, 0:0.001:0.5);

% Second step function at t=0.3
[y_b, T_b] = step(transfun, 0.3:0.001:0.5);

% How to add the above two outputs together?
plot( ???? )
```

I've searched google, but the only solutions I can find are for systems with multiple inputs (MIMO). This system has only one input, I just want to use superposition principal to add them together.

When I try adding the two vectors together I get "Vectors must be the same lengths."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't the step response. The step response measures the system's ability to track a constant input, and what you're proposing isn't a constant input.

To do what you want, look into the [lsim function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/control/ref/lsim.html) and the [gensig function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/control/ref/gensig.html).

(Side note: As for why you couldn't add your vectors, the first goes from 0 to 0.5 in 0.001 increments, and the other goes from 0.3 to 0.5 in 0.001 increments. Of course they're going to be different lengths! If you're really intent on adding these together, do something like:

```
[y_b, T_b] = step(transfun, 0:0.001:0.5);
y_b(T_b<0.3) = 0;
```

I can't test this at the moment, but if that doesn't work, try:

```
y_b(0:0.001:0.3) = 0;
```

)

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks. I didn't understand the problem correctly - what I actually needed to do was add a step input, as well as a second step input at a different point in the system (after a gain) to simulate a steady state error. I ended up creating a model in Simulink.

Comment: Good call. I wanted to suggest Simulink, but I felt like it might be a little too far from your problem. Simulink is definitely a much better way to do it.